# how to create a attached property of BindingBase Type and receive value from binding expression

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

the requirement is to export data from datagrid to excel file, but for datagridtemplatecolumn it's not reasonable to export the content. To solve this problem, I tried to add a attached property on datagridtemplatecolumn, the type of the property is bindingbase, so i can use the bindingbase object to get a value from the datacontext to export.

The attached property is similar to DataGridTextColumn.Binding，but it seems not possible to assign value to the property with "{Binding xxx}" expression.

So, is it possible to create an attached property of BindingBase Type? Or if there is another way to solve my problem?

Comment: Why use BindingBase as property type instead of the actual result type of the Binding? Since it's a dependency property, you can assign a regular Binding to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add a ExportPropertyPath Attached property to the DataGridColumn, which solved this problem.